# Rendered image and Preview Not Matching at all

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image: Why do the colors look so different in my viewport vs render is my main question. When other people open my file in their pc their viewport matches my render but in my pc it doesn't :')]Have faced this similar problem before so this time I updated to the latest Blender 4 but still facing the same problem. Have searched for solutions but nothing helped so far.

This is what the final render looks like
[image: This is what the final render looks like]

This is what the preview looks like
[image: This is what the preview looks like]

file:
[image]

Comment: Hello maybe you have overlapping objects? Please share your file (only this object): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi. I've added the file to my post. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: the *Subdivision Surface* modifier has different levels for the viewport and render

Comment: @Blunder i've set them as the same yet no difference :')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change solidify offset to 0 and you will get:

[image]

Comment: So what was the problem exactly?

Comment: @moonboots: I have no idea, i hoped he just wanted a solution - not a detailed explanation ;) his offset was at -1

Comment: @Chris Why do the colors look different in my viewport vs render though :') that's the main issue I need the solution to

Comment: @Ardragonuv: that's what i wrote: change offset in solidify modifier to 0. That's the solution. Did u try it?

Comment: @Chris yes I just applied the solidify modifier and that worked as well ❤️